# Adding checkbox functionality to to-do app with Parse backend

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, checkbox, parse-platform

I'm having some trouble figuring out of how make the connection between my app and Parse when a user completes a task in my to-do app. I have created the PFObject for it and I have connected the label up and that works great but I am trying to figure out how to work with Bools in Parse.

```
let obj = PFObject(className: "Tasks")
                obj.setValue(task, forKey: "task")
                obj.setValue(self.team, forKey: "team")
                obj.setValue(self.checked.isChecked, forKey: "done")
                obj.saveInBackgroundWithBlock() {success,error in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }
                    if success {
                        self.loadTasks()
                        // self.tasks.insert(obj, atIndex: 0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }))
```

"checked" is the class instance of CheckBox (all of the brains of the button/checkbox) and "isChecked" is a Bool with a didSet property that changes the checkbox to checked or unchecked based on whether the button is tapped.

The checkbox works great in the app, it just doesn't sync that action.

This is what I have tried so far but to no avail...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.selectionStyle = .None
        let idx = tasks[indexPath.row]
        let task = idx["task"] as! String
        if let label = cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel {
            label.text = task
        }
        
        let done = idx["done"] as! Bool
        if let checkBox = cell.viewWithTag(2) as? UIButton {
            checked.isChecked = done
        }
    

        return cell
    }
```

Any and all help is welcome.

#### EDIT

I figured out how to create the value and save it to Parse but now I'm having trouble editing that value and sending that new info to Parse. When I refresh the data it just goes back to the default value (false).

```
let done = idx["done"] as! Bool
        if let checkBox = cell.viewWithTag(2) as? CheckBox {
            CheckBox.isChecked = done
        }
```

How do I save the new value?